# Need to Check if a Table Exists Before Deleting a Record

Tags: mysql, query, error-handling

I have the following SQL query in my Ruby app:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM `#{database}`.`table1` WHERE `same_id` = #{some_id};"
```

The problem is that in rare circumstances `table1` might not exist. I need to construct this query so even if the table does not exist SQL does not throw an error.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 8):

You should probably use a stored procedure to to do this:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`DeleteByID` $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`DeleteByID` (db VARCHAR(64),tb VARCHAR(64),id_to_delete INT) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE FoundCount INT;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO FoundCount
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = db
    AND table_name = tb;

    IF FoundCount = 1 THEN
        SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',db,'.',tb,' WHERE id=',id_to_delete); 
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
        EXECUTE stmt; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;

END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

All you do in your code is call the stored procedure. For example, to delete ID 128 from `drupaldb.comments`:

```
CALL test.DeleteByID('drupaldb','comments',128);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Another variation on this would be to sculpt the query directly:

```
set @given_db = 'drupaldb';
set @given_tb = 'comments';
set @given_id = 128;
set @good_sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',@given_db,'.',@given_tb,' WHERE id=',@given_id);
set @evil_sql = 'SELECT 1';
SELECT IF(table_exists=1,@good_sql,@evil_sql) INTO @DeleteSQL
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) table_exists
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema=@given_db
    AND table_name=@given_tb
) A;
PREPARE stmt FROM @DeleteSQL; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

NOTE: If the table does not exist, the query executed is `SELECT 1`.

Here is a sample that shows if the table does not exist:

```
mysql>     set @given_db = 'drupaldb';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     set @given_tb = 'comments';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     set @given_id = 128;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     set @good_sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',@given_db,'.',@given_tb,' WHERE id=',@given_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     set @evil_sql = 'SELECT 1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     SELECT IF(table_exists=1,@good_sql,@evil_sql) INTO @DeleteSQL
    ->     FROM
    ->     (
    ->         SELECT COUNT(1) table_exists
    ->         FROM information_schema.tables
    ->         WHERE table_schema=@given_db
    ->         AND table_name=@given_tb
    ->     ) A;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     PREPARE stmt FROM @DeleteSQL; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now, here is a sample where the table exists:

```
mysql> select count(1) from mysql.user where user='rolando';
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all on *.* to 'rolando'@'127.0.0.1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from mysql.user where user='rolando';
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @given_db = 'mysql';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @given_tb = 'user';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @given_id = 'rolando';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @good_sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',@given_db,'.',@given_tb,' WHERE user=''',@given_id,'''');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @evil_sql = 'SELECT 1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(table_exists=1,@good_sql,@evil_sql) INTO @DeleteSQL
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT COUNT(1) table_exists
    ->     FROM information_schema.tables
    ->     WHERE table_schema=@given_db
    ->     AND table_name=@given_tb
    -> ) A;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @DeleteSQL; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Statement prepared

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from mysql.user where user='rolando';
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a version where this works, as CONCAT function is only available 2012+...

Comment: @fireshark519 MySQL 5.0 has `CONCAT()` as a function. You might be encountering the same problem someone had in November 2010 in StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148149/mysql-5-0-reporting-concat-does-not-exist). Another website states that `CONCAT()` goes back to MySQL 3.23 (https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/concat.php)

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, the [IGNORE option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) will treat errors as warnings.

```
DELETE IGNORE ...
```

> The IGNORE keyword causes MySQL to ignore all errors during the
>   process of deleting rows. (Errors encountered during the parsing stage
>   are processed in the usual manner.) Errors that are ignored due to the
>   use of IGNORE are returned as warnings.

I'm not sure whether MySQL would treat a non-existent table as "an error in the parsing stage". If it does, you can [query the information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) for a table name. Something along these lines should work.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your database name'
AND table_name = 'your table name';
```

Temporary tables don't appear in the information_schema views. If your table is a temporary table, then you have a bug in your code. You're dropping the table before you're finished with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.

I tried using IGNORE to no avail, I guess the non-existent table is found during the parsing stage. 

How would I construct the SELECT and DELETE as one query? From what I understand I can't use IF statements because MySQL only supports them as stored procedures.

Comment: You can't do it in a single statement. Why don't you want to handle the error in Ruby?  (It doesn't make sense to *not* handle errors in Ruby.)

Comment: tip on the database name, you can just use DATABASE() to use the currently selected schema.

Comment: `DELETE IGNORE` does not silence the error on a non-existent table.  `#1146 - Table 'nonexistent_tablename' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 3):

I would test the table exists first, by running a query such as;

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table1';
```

And then perform the delete based on the results of that query. If the table exists, a single record is returned containing the table name.